# Is there any built-in method for getting all controller list with function name?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any built-in method for getting controllers list with their function names  as follows:

```
$routes = array( 
                'contoller1' => array('index','delete','store'),
                'contoller2' => array('index','delete','show'),
                'contoller3' => array('show','insertData','delete'),
                ......
                ..
            );
```

Maybe it is possible to find controllers from Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes().
`var_dump(Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes());`

But it returns a very large array with lots of info

Comment: In laravel, there are separate files for each controller just like codeigniter?

Comment: I need two dimensional array with controller name and function name withing a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getRoutes`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_getRoutes) then [`getPath`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getPath) and [`getAction`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getAction)

```
// Get a collection of all the routes
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

// Create your base array of routes
$routes = [];

// loop through the collection of routes
foreach ($routeCollection as $route) {

    // get the action which is an array of items
    $action = $route->getAction();

    // if the action has the key 'controller' 
    if (array_key_exists('controller', $action)) {

        // explode the string with @ creating an array with a count of 2
        $explodedAction = explode('@', $action['controller']);

        // check to see if an array exists for the controller name
        if (!isset($routes[$explodedAction[0]])) {

            // if not create it, this will look like
            // $routes['controllerName']
            $routes[$explodedAction[0]] = [];
        }
        // set the add the method name to the controller array
        $routes[$explodedAction[0]][] = $explodedAction[1];
    }
}

// show the glory of your work
dd($routes);
```

Comment: i actually need two dimensional array where key will be the controller name and values array contain function name. What i am mansion above

Comment: Thanks @whoacowboy. That's means i have to do it with above code there is no built-in method for found this?

Comment: @PayerAhammed - There is no built in method, because you have a very specific use case which almost nobody ever needs to do. Further, why would there be a specific method to format your routes in an array exactly the way you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

When you type `php artisan routes` or `php artisan route:list`, depending on framework version it gets a list of all the routes and associated controllers.

So if you go into the source code, you can see exactly how to get what you are looking for.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RoutesCommand.php

Lines 82 to 112 show you how to compile the routes into a displayable format.

Shamelessly plagarised from the source code for reference.

```
/**
 * Compile the routes into a displayable format.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getRoutes()
{
    $results = array();

    foreach ($this->routes as $route)
    {
        $results[] = $this->getRouteInformation($route);
    }

    return array_filter($results);
}

/**
 * Get the route information for a given route.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
 * @return array
 */
protected function getRouteInformation(Route $route)
{
    $uri = implode('|', $route->methods()).' '.$route->uri();

    return $this->filterRoute(array(
        'host'   => $route->domain(),
        'uri'    => $uri,
        'name'   => $route->getName(),
        'action' => $route->getActionName(),
        'before' => $this->getBeforeFilters($route),
        'after'  => $this->getAfterFilters($route)
    ));
}
```

You probably only want to iterate over ang get the action name. `$route->getActionName();`

Or the simple way:

```
    $routes = app()['router']->getRoutes();

    $controllers = [];
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $controllers[] = $route->getAction();
    }

    $collection = [];
    foreach ($controllers as $c) {
       explode ( "@" , $c, 1 )
       if (!isset($collection[$c[0]])) {
          $collection[$c[0]] = [];
       }
       $collection[$c[0]][] = $c[1];
    }

    dd($collection);
```

Comment: i actually need two dimensional array where key will be the controller name and values  array contain function name.

Comment: @PayerAhammed - Please see updated answer. It's completely untested and written on the fly so will probably contain bugs so dont just copy and paste saying it doesnt work! Hopefully it will point you in the right direction though.

Comment: it's says `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`